# In ColdFusion can I capture closed-over variables by value?

Tags: coldfusion, closures

Say we're building a list of closures that perform some function on a value `i` where `i` is a new value every iteration. For example:

```
function foo() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arrayAppend(result, function() { return i; });
    }
    return result;
}

flist = foo();
newline = "<br>";
for (f in flist) {
    WriteOutput(f() & newline);
}
```

It appears that CF is capturing `i` by reference--the result of the above is:

```
4
4
4
4
```

These results are the same across CF2011, CF2016, Lucee4.5 and Lucee5 (I tested via trycf.com, handy, assuming it really is running those engines).

I have implemented a round-about way of what I call a `value_capturing_closure`, but don't really want to foist it on my team, as it would be best to stick with CF idioms everyone is familiar with. Is it possible in CF, using native CF closure syntax, to capture variables by value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how closures work. What you will need to do is cause a copy of the value to occur and for that copy to be bound to a function that is not persisted. This can be accomplished by creating a function that accepts an argument and then creates a function.

```
function foo() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arrayAppend(result, function(x) {   
            return function(){ return x };
        }(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

or separate for clarity into a separate function

```
function foo() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arrayAppend(result, createClosure(i));
    }
    return result;
}


function createClosure(x) {
    return function() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially how I've implemented my existing solution (with some extra spice to deal with variadics). Hm—Python appears to work the same, at least in a quick test I just did; guess I should hit the books.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Robert says above, the key is to capture the iteration at the time you create the function by passing into the function as you create it.

So your code could be written like this on Lucee:

```
function foo() {
    var f = (n) => () => n;
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arrayAppend(result, f(i));
    }
    return result;
}

flist = foo();
newline = "<br>";
for (f in flist) {
    WriteOutput(f() & newline);
}
```

https://www.trycf.com/gist/c1f521fa190e6d32aa07de93d13580d8/lucee5?theme=monokai

ACF 2018 update 5 should also support that fat arrow syntax, but I can't test that at the moment.

Comment: cffiddle seems to be broken at the moment :(